# Finding values in pandas dataframe for a particular column based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python - 3.6 and pandas - 0.24.1

I have a pandas dataframe `df1`:

```
    col1    col2
0  8388611  3.9386
1  8388612  1.9386
```

I need to find the value of `col1` on a particular index

```
 print(df1['col1'][1])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2656, inget_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(df1['col1'][1])
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py", line 2397, in get_loc
    loc = self._get_level_indexer(key, level=0)
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py", line 2652, in _get_level_indexer
    code = level_index.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2658, inget_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1
```

What's the ideal way to iterate over all the elements of a particular column in pandas?

Comment: Use `print(df1.loc[1, 'col1'])`, it is dupe

Answer (score 7):

You can use iloc

`df["column"].iloc[index]`